# Update resource files in assemblie

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, embedded-resource, resx

the website i'm working on has resource files for a number of languages.

The resources of the website are compiled in the website dll (i think?) and the resources from other, from the website, referenced dll's, are stored in subfolders of the \bin directory.

So i have in the bin my website.dll, and a subfolder called es with the Spanish resources for the website.services project (called website.services.resources.dll) and so on.

Now we have the site live, and there is a wish for a immediate change of one of the items in a resource file.

As my .resx files are compiled, i have to change the resource in the dll.

Is that possible?

Comment: you don't have access to the original source?

Comment: yes, i have access to the original source

Answer (score 0):

Just change the specified item in the rsex file. Compile it again and replace the DLL. I think it will work.

Comment: you mean change and compile it in Visual Studio? Then i change the website.dll itself also. I was looking for a way to change it without touching my current code, and if possible, on the server.

Comment: To edit without the source code, you may need to perform a reverse engineering  for which you'll need other software tools.

Answer (score 0):

another approach could be to copy up your project to the server, in it's entirety.  Then the runtime on the server will compile the app for you.  Then when you next make a change to the resx file the runtime will re-compile the app and pickup the change.

Downside to this when you make a change to the resx your users may notice the site stop working and may lose any session variables (if i remember correctly).